# Javascript - Remove last with global modifier not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex like this:

```
("2*").replace(/[\+\-\*\/]$/g, "") -> "2"
```

And even though if it has the global modifier this won't work:

```
("2**").replace(/[\+\-\*\/]$/g, "") -> "2*"
```

How do you fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) with your character class. The `+` quantifier means "one or more" times. Also you can avoid escaping certain characters inside of your class and remove the global modifier.

```
'2*****'.replace(/[-+*/]+$/, '') //=> "2"
```

Explanation:

```
[-+*/]+  # any character of: '-', '+', '*', '/' (1 or more times)
      $  # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: Inside a `[]` you don't even have to escape the delimiter (`/`). But: readability, consistency etc, I know.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `/[-+*/]+$/` will work fine. Inside brackets, you don't have to escape a lot. `]` of course, and sometimes `-` and maybe more, but not the delimiter. Not very important though, and it's probably good practice to always escape `/`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
"2**".replace(/[\+\-\*\/]+$/, "")
```

You can also try:

```
"2**".replace(/[-+*/]+$/, "");
```

Suggested by  l'L'l. Or use negation:

```
"2**".replace(/[^0-9]+$/, "");
```

Comment: Do you really need the global modifier for that?

Comment: No. In this case global modifier is redundant. I edited the code.

Comment: If you put the `-` first in the character class then all you need to escape is `/`

Comment: @l'L'l You don't have to escape `/` inside brackets. `/[-+*/]+$/` will work fine.